# Bundle enterprise library instead of installing

Tags: c#, enterprise, enterprise-library

does anybody know if it's possible (or have experience doing so) to simply bundle the microsoft enterprise library components in a .net solution instead of performing the installation?  I'm trying to avoid putting a customer through the installation step.
Thanks for your response!!  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. If you look at [SCSF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480482.aspx) you will see that SCSF wizards creates a */Lib* directory full of entlib dlls and all of the project of this solution references they.

There is the list of */Lib* (of course you should exclude *SmartClient* assemblies):

```
Microsoft.Practices.CompositeUI.dll
Microsoft.Practices.CompositeUI.WinForms.dll
Microsoft.Practices.CompositeUI.WPF.dll
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.dll
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.SqlCe.dll
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.dll
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging.dll
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.dll
Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.dll
Microsoft.Practices.SmartClient.ConnectionMonitor.dll
Microsoft.Practices.SmartClient.DisconnectedAgent.dll
Microsoft.Practices.SmartClient.EndpointCatalog.dll
Microsoft.Practices.SmartClient.EnterpriseLibrary.dll
```

Comment: I have done so on several live production solutions, and not had any problems.

Comment: Be aware that there are SIGNED versions of these assemblies and UNSIGNED versions of these assemblies.  But yes, all you need is to copy and reference them to include them with a DotNet package.